# Approximate an operator by a sequence of operators with finite spectrum

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $T$ is a positive invertible element in $B(H)$. Does there exits a sequence $T_n$ of positive invertible operators with finite spectrum such that $T_n$ converges to $T$?

I know the following fact:Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert-space and $A:H\to H$ be a normal operator. There is a unique spectral measure $\Phi$ on the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ such that  $f(A) = \int_{\sigma(A)} f d \Phi$ for any continuous function $f$ on the spectrum $\sigma(A)$.

Then $T=\int_{\sigma(A)} \iota d \Phi$,where $\iota (z)=z$.How to choose the sequence $T_n$ such that $\sigma(T_n)$ is finite and $T_n \to T$?

Comment: Hint: You can approximate a non-zero, positive, measurable function by simple functions. What does the von Neumann algebra generated by a normal operator look like?

Comment: You mean $\iota $ can be approximated by a sequence of simple functions $f_n$?But how to assure that $\int_{\sigma(A)} f_n \Phi$ is also positive and invertible?